# Linq to Entities Skip() and Take()

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am working on an ASP.NET application and I am creating a LINQ query which will select paginated records from db. on user interface I have a listbox where user can select multiple choices. I want to know:

- How can I increment Skip(), Take() parameters to view next results ?
- How can I use "IN" key word so that if user selects multiple options from listbox, query can check all values ?

My query looks like this:

```
var searchResults = context.data_vault.Where(d => d.STATE == lstStates.SelectedItem.Text).OrderBy(d= > d.dv_id).Take(10).Skip(2);    
GridView1.DataSource = searchResults;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You need to first call skip and then take. In your current implementation you will always retrieve the items 3 to 10, because you take the first 10 and from those you skip the first two. To increment you only need to supply the value for skip as a parameter to your method where the query is executed.

Answer (score 22):

I think you are using Skip incorrectly.  It should be before the Take.

Skip skips a number of records, so for your first page, pass in 0, else pass in the (page number - 1) * records per page.

I usually do something like this:

```
int Page = 1;
int RecordsPerPage = 10;
var q = yourQuery.Skip((Page - 1) * RecordsPerPage).Take(RecordsPerPage);
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to turn paging on the GridView first. Then on `PageIndexChanging` event:

```
var result = db.Where(...)
               .Skip(e.NewPageIndex * grid.PageSize)
               .Take(grid.PageSize)
               .ToList(); // this is very important part too
```

To emulate `IN` behavior:

```
var selection = list.SelectedItems.Select(i => i.Text).ToArray();
var result = db.Where(x => selection.Contains(x.Prop));
```

Comment: Add Closing brackets in second query. `db.Where(x => selection.Contains(x.Prop));`

Comment: @abatishchev What I need to write on page load ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Bind the list onto the GridView. Then it will perform paging by itself.

Comment: but it will slow down things because on page load it will bring all records ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: No, EF will limit query result. Of course it will be less efficient then manual limiting (that's a known issue of SQL Server).

Comment: Also, I see that var selection = list.SelectedItems.Select(i => i.Text).ToArray();   list.selectedItems doesn't exist.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: `list` means your `lstStates`. What is its type? I thought this is `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox`.

Comment: yes it is listbox control but still not showing this selecteditems

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Indeed, only `SelectedItem`. How do you receive multiple selection from user?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Have I answered the original question? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   int temp = (CurrentPageNumber - 1) * 10;
    var searchResults = context.data_vault.Where(d => d.STATE == lstStates.SelectedItem.Text).OrderBy(d= > d.dv_id).Skip(temp).Take(10);
```