# ASP MVC Paging with LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 100 record. I want LINQ for this:

```
int pageNumber = get from user; // for example 2 , 3 ,...
if pageNumber == 2
   return records 20 to 29
```

Thanks!

Comment: use skip and take, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950388/linq-to-entities-skip-and-take

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want probably is the following:

```
var itemsToShow = items.OrderBy(p => p.Id)
                       .Skip((currentPage - 1) * numPerPage)
                       .Take(numPerPage);
```

Where you are ordering pages by `Id` property and you have variables `currentPage` holding the number of the current page and `numPerPage` holding the number of items per page.

You probably would like then to make a type containing the paging info to make your life easier. Something like

```
public class PagingInfo
{
     public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
     public int NumItems { get; set; }
     public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
     public int TotalPages
     {
         get
         {
             return Math.Ceiling((double)NumItems/ItemsPerPage);
         }
     }
}
```

Then your `currentPage` would be `pagingInfo.CurrentPage` and your `numPerPage` would be `pagingInfo.ItemsPerPage`. In addition you have a property to get the total number of pages which can be useful. This is a good approach so that you can transport information about paging on view models.

Comment: Please remove the last sentence, it is not necessary and it's `items` btw ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
int Page = 1;
int RecordsPerPage = 10;
var q = yourQuery.Skip((Page - 1) * RecordsPerPage).Take(RecordsPerPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest to use PagedList.MVC its a free library witch is available on Nuget:
here is an example:
this is going to be your action:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int page = 1)
    {
        //_db is my sample data context but paged list works for any IEnumerable
        //since this is an extension method
        var model = 
            _db.Comments
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.Date)
            .ToPagedList(page, 10);

        return View(model);
    }
```

i`v set model for view as an IPagedList, this is the view:
nice thing is that it will automaticlly generate page links.

```
<div class="pager">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }),    PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast)
</div>
```

its customizable (via css).
this is the nuget page:
[PagedList.MVC nuget page](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/4.5.0)